# CloudFormation : Create VPC Endpoint in the VPC in which a lambda is running

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I have a lambda function that is running in a VPC.
I need to create an endpoint in this VPC with a service name that I have. I have already created one and tested the connection to service from lambda by doing everything via console. But now I need to do this in the CFT.
 I know how to create a VPC Endpoint but can't figure out how to link the endpoint to the VPC Id of the VPC in which the lambda is running.

This is how I created the lambda to run in VPC.

```yml
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
  Handler: 'handleRequest'
  Runtime: java8
  CodeUri:
    Bucket: {}
    Key: BATS::SAM::CodeS3Key
  Description: Lambda.
  Timeout: 20
  Role:
    Fn::GetAtt: [LambdaRole, Arn]
  VpcConfig:
    Fn::If:
    - RunLambdaInVPC
    - SecurityGroupIds: [{Ref: LambdaSecurityGroup}]
      SubnetIds:
      - {'Fn::ImportValue': PrivateSubnet01}
      - {'Fn::ImportValue': PrivateSubnet02}
    - {Ref: 'AWS::NoValue'}
```

Below is the VPC Endpoint I am creating but cannot see how to I provide the VPC Id :

```yml
Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
Properties:
  SecurityGroupIds: [{Ref: LambdaSecurityGroup}]
  ServiceName: 'ServiceName'
  SubnetIds:
    - {'Fn::ImportValue': PrivateSubnet01}
    - {'Fn::ImportValue': PrivateSubnet02}
  VpcId : <??>
```

Comment: The VpcId attribute is `The ID of the VPC in which the endpoint will be used.` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpcendpoint.html#cfn-ec2-vpcendpoint-vpcid

Comment: @AmitBaranes I am aware of that, the question is how do I get the Id of the VPC ? I can see in the console the Id of the VPC that was created by default by the stack when I created the lambda but I do not think that's an appropriate way to create dependency on hardcoded value.

Comment: VPCs are not created dynamically, so you should absolutely code this as a config (or env var). Spinning up a private network requires knowledge of all private CIDRs to prevent collision.

Comment: @iammrmehul It appears that the template is importing Subnet information from another stack. Can that other stack also export the VPC ID?

Comment: @LostJon The private network is actually already setup and tested. My only concern is the DNS Server name that is created in the private link VPCE (which I use to hit the destination service) is hardcoded basically. I want to make this a part of CFT by setting up VPCE in the CFT and then using Fn::GetAttr on it to get the DNS Server names.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I see in the [AWS::ECU::Subnet aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnet.html#aws-resource-ec2-subnet-return-values) that Subnets can return the VPC ID. Can I simply use `Fn::GetAtt: [PrivateSubnet01, VpcId]` as the value ?

Comment: @iammrmehul By all means try it, but I fear that `PrivateSubnet01` is coming in as a string name and that `GetAtt` might instead require the _object_ that is created by the stack (since it wouldn't know how to get an attribute related to a string). Let us know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your question to @JohnRotenstein ...

> I see in the AWS::ECU::Subnet aws docs that Subnets can return the VPC ID. Can I simply use Fn::GetAtt: [PrivateSubnet01, VpcId] as the value?

No, you cannot. You can get the VPC ID from a subnet *resource* in the template that created the subnet, but you're not in that template and don't have a subnet resource. You have a subnet ID (that is just a string such as "subnet-1234abcd").

So, modify the original template that created the VPC (and output the subnet IDs) so that it also outputs the VPC ID. Then import that VPC ID into your new template.